# CAGL: How to specify the number of remained vertices when simplifying meshs?

Tags: mesh

**My question is how to simplify a mesh object to the number of vertices.**

In detail, I'm using ModelNet40, in which the number of mesh vertices varies, and I want to unify the number of vertices to 5000. That means I have to drop mesh objects owning less than 5000 vertices and simplify mesh objects owning over 5000 vertices.

I've googled a geometry algorithm tool named [CAGL](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Surface_mesh_simplification/index.html). But CAGL only provide constraint on edge number when doing mesh collapsing.

Here's the example of mesh simplification process, where `stop_n` define the number of remained edges. **Is there any way to define the remained vertices?**

```cpp
#include <CGAL/Simple_cartesian.h>
#include <CGAL/Surface_mesh.h>
#include <CGAL/Surface_mesh_simplification/edge_collapse.h>
#include <CGAL/Surface_mesh_simplification/Policies/Edge_collapse/Count_stop_predicate.h>
#include <chrono>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
typedef CGAL::Simple_cartesian<double>               Kernel;
typedef Kernel::Point_3                              Point_3;
typedef CGAL::Surface_mesh<Point_3>                  Surface_mesh;
namespace SMS = CGAL::Surface_mesh_simplification;
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  /** load mesh from file */
  int num_of_vertices = 5000;
  Surface_mesh surface_mesh;
  const std::string filename = (argc > 1) ? argv[1] : CGAL::data_file_path("out.off");
  std::ifstream is(filename);
  if(!is || !(is >> surface_mesh))
  {
    std::cerr << "Failed to read input mesh: " << filename << std::endl;
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }
  if(!CGAL::is_triangle_mesh(surface_mesh))
  {
    std::cerr << "Input geometry is not triangulated." << std::endl;
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }
  std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point start_time = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
  int current_vertices = surface_mesh.number_of_vertices();
  int current_edges = surface_mesh.number_of_edges();
  int stop_n = current_edges - (current_vertices - num_of_vertices);
  std::cout << "(v, e)=" << current_vertices << " "<< current_edges << " stop_n=" << stop_n << std::endl;

  /** a stop predicate regulate the number of remained edges */
  SMS::Count_stop_predicate<Surface_mesh> stop(stop_n);
  int r = SMS::edge_collapse(surface_mesh, stop);

  /** end and save */
  std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point end_time = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
  std::cout << "Finished!\n" << r << " edges removed.\n" << surface_mesh.number_of_edges() << " final edges, " << surface_mesh.number_of_vertices() << " final vertices.\n";
  std::cout << "Time elapsed: " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end_time - start_time).count() << "ms" << std::endl;
  CGAL::IO::write_polygon_mesh((argc > 3) ? argv[3] : "out.off", surface_mesh, CGAL::parameters::stream_precision(17));
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this could be a solution:

```cpp
#include <CGAL/Simple_cartesian.h>
#include <CGAL/Surface_mesh.h>
// Simplification function
#include <CGAL/Surface_mesh_simplification/edge_collapse.h>
// Visitor base
#include <CGAL/Surface_mesh_simplification/Edge_collapse_visitor_base.h>
// Stop-condition policy
#include <CGAL/Surface_mesh_simplification/Policies/Edge_collapse/Count_ratio_stop_predicate.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
typedef CGAL::Simple_cartesian<double>                                  Kernel;
typedef Kernel::Point_3                                                 Point_3;
typedef CGAL::Surface_mesh<Point_3>                                     Surface_mesh;
typedef boost::graph_traits<Surface_mesh>::halfedge_descriptor          halfedge_descriptor;
typedef boost::graph_traits<Surface_mesh>::vertex_descriptor            vertex_descriptor;
namespace SMS = CGAL::Surface_mesh_simplification;
typedef SMS::Edge_profile<Surface_mesh>                                 Profile;
// The following is a Visitor that keeps track of the simplification process.
// In this example the progress is printed real-time and a few statistics are
// recorded (and printed in the end).
//
template<class TM_>
class Count_vertex_stop_predicate{
public:
    typedef TM_                                                 TM;
    typedef typename boost::graph_traits<TM>::edges_size_type   size_type;
    Count_vertex_stop_predicate(const unsigned int N, const int num)
        : m_v(num), N(N)
    {
        CGAL_warning(num > 0);
    }
    template <typename F, typename Profile>
    bool operator()(const F& /*current_cost*/,
                    const Profile& profile,
                    size_type /*initial_edge_count*/,
                    size_type /*current_edge_count*/) const
    {
        const TM& sm = profile.surface_mesh();
//        std::cerr << "\rinfo: " << N - sm.number_of_removed_vertices() << " < " << m_v << std::flush;
        return N - sm.number_of_removed_vertices() <= m_v;
    }
private:
    int m_v;
    unsigned int N;
};

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    Surface_mesh surface_mesh;
    const std::string filename = CGAL::data_file_path(argv[1]);
    std::cout << filename << std::endl;
    std::ifstream is(filename);
    if(!is || !(is >> surface_mesh))
    {
        std::cerr << "Failed to read input mesh: " << filename << std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    if(!CGAL::is_triangle_mesh(surface_mesh))
    {
        std::cerr << "Input geometry is not triangulated." << std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    std::cout << "Initial Vertices: " << surface_mesh.number_of_vertices() << std::endl
              << "Initial Edges: " << surface_mesh.number_of_edges() << std::endl;
    // In this example, the simplification stops when the number of undirected edges
    // drops below xx% of the initial count
    Count_vertex_stop_predicate<Surface_mesh> stop(surface_mesh.number_of_vertices(), 5000);
    // The index maps are not explicitelty passed as in the previous
    // example because the surface mesh items have a proper id() field.
    // On the other hand, we pass here explicit cost and placement
    // function which differ from the default policies, ommited in
    // the previous example.
    int r = SMS::edge_collapse(surface_mesh, stop);
    std::cout << "\nFinished!\n" << r << " edges removed.\n"
              << surface_mesh.number_of_edges() << " final edges.\n"
              << surface_mesh.number_of_vertices() << " final vertices.\n";
    CGAL::IO::write_polygon_mesh("out.off", surface_mesh, CGAL::parameters::stream_precision(17));
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```